# android Googlemaps java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppIndex

Tags: android

I'm getting very frustrating error when integrating with google maps. Can someone kindly explain what I'm doing wrong to cause the below error:

This is **Error**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppIndex: The android-app URI host must match the package name and follow the format android-app://<package_name>/<scheme>/<host_path>.
```

Provided URI: android-app://app.facebook.android.com.googlemaps/http/host/path

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, I had copied code from a different source. This is how the onStart method that was throwing the exception looked like:

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        googleApiClient.connect();
        super.onStart();
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Map Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://app.facebook.android.com.googlemaps/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(googleApiClient, viewAction);
    }
```

I just had to change app.facebook.android.com.googlemaps to match my main activity package name.